# htaccess rewrite url parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect

> http://localhost:8080/mypproject/?supplier=test123

to

> http://localhost:8080/myproject/?product_cat=test123

But I don't know how...

Comment: showing us what you've tried so far is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/myproject/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^supplier=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ ?product_cat=%1 [L,R=301]
```